# How to handle two submit buttons in a jsp file

Tags: jsp, servlets

Im having a jsp page with two submit buttons as shown below

```
 <form name="myForm" action="app" method="post">
    <select name="selection" multiple="multiple" id="select" required>
        <option value="">Select Languages....</option>
        <option value="nl_value">Dutch</option>
        <option value="en_string">English</option>
        <option value="fr_value">French</option>
        <option value="de_value">German</option>
        <option value="es_value">Spanish</option>
    </select> <br> <br> <br> 
    <input type="submit" name="translate" value="Translate"> 
    <input type="submit" name="tableData" value="GetFullStringsContent">
</form>
```

For the first submit button it is mandatory to select an item in drop down so i kept that `<select>` tag as required and for the next submit button it is optional

after submitting it will go to

```
 @WebServlet(value = "/app")
 public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if (req.getParameter("tableData") != null) {
        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("application.jsp");
        rd.forward(req, resp);
    } else if (req.getParameter("translate") != null) {
        String[] str = req.getParameterValues("selection");
        String columns = "";
 //next there is some logic
```

But when I click the second button the request is not forwarding to required jsp. Give me a solution

Comment: for both the buttons the "required" remains the same. You could have an additional function that removes the "required" attribute of the `select` when you click the second button and then submits. Please try this and ask if you face issues.

Comment: Any idea of doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could an `onclick` on the `GetFullStringsContent` and in the function remove the "required" on the `select` when you click it

```js
function test(){
  $("select[name=selection]").removeAttr('required');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" action="app" method="post">
    <select name="selection" multiple="multiple" id="select" required>
        <option value="">Select Languages....</option>
        <option value="nl_value">Dutch</option>
        <option value="en_string">English</option>
        <option value="fr_value">French</option>
        <option value="de_value">German</option>
        <option value="es_value">Spanish</option>
    </select> <br> <br> <br> 
    <input type="submit" name="translate" value="Translate"> 
    <input type="submit" onclick="test()" name="tableData" value="GetFullStringsContent">
</form>
```